# MediaElement is playing audio only in debug mode, its not playing audio without debug mode

Tags: debugging, audio, windows-phone-8, mediaelement, audio-player

I am working on windows phone 8 trying to implement the audio playing feature in my app by creating the user control and media element.

Surprisingly audio is playing during debugging but as i run the app without debug mode audio does not play, i tried the await and async methodology but thats also not working.

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private async void AudioControl(string audioId, string audio_url)
{
   customControlAudioPlayer.media_Id = audioId;
   customAudioPlayer.media_Url = audio_url;
   //Following function is dedicated to show control and play the audio.
   await customAudioPlayer.RenderView();
   gridContainsMediaElement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
xmlns:MyControls="clr-namespace:dbok.Controls"

<Grid Name="gridContainsMediaElement"  
      VerticalAlignment="Top"  
      Background="Black" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <MyControls:AudioPlayerControl 
           x:Name="customControlAudioPlayer"/>
       <!--CloseClick="audioPlayerControl_CloseClick"-->
</Grid>
```

**CustomControlPlayer.xaml**

```
 <Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}"  >

        <MediaElement x:Name="audioMediaElement" AutoPlay="False" 
            Grid.Row="0" 
            MediaOpened="audioMediaElement_MediaOpened"
            MediaEnded="audioMediaElement_MediaEnded"
                    MediaFailed="audioMediaElement_MediaFailed"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="05" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

    <Slider Visibility="Visible" Margin="50,0,50,0"
            x:Name="mediaPositionSlider" Background="#f1592a" 
            Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0" 
            />

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**CustomControlPlayer.xaml.cs**

```
 public string media_Id;
 public string media_Url;

 public async Task RenderView()
 {
    Uri file_url;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(media_Url, UriKind.Absolute, out file_url))
    {
        myElement.Source = file_url;
        myElement.Play();

        //I tried by check the media element state but its executing and playing only in debug mode. it was not working for me without debug i made it commented.
        //if (myElement.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Playing)
        //{
        //    myElement.Play();
        //}
        mediaPositionSlider.Value = 0;
        UpdateDuration(0);
   }

//-----------

private void UpdateDuration(double _myValue)
{
    TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_myValue);
    string time_slot = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
                   t.Hours,
                   t.Minutes,
                   t.Seconds);
    PlayStatusLabel.Text = time_slot.ToString();
}
```

I have post my code, where & what i am doing wrong by which its not playing in run mode inplace of debug mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully solved the issue i was facing, actually what happening when cursor reach on audioMediaElement.Play(); the Play() function takes time to execute internally, what i did i replace audioMediaElement.Play() to audioMediaElement.AutoPlay = true; and it started working. :) woooo hoooo... :)