# sound plays in debug mode but not release mode

Tags: c#, audio

When i run debug mode program plays wav file, when i run the app, i get no sound. Can anyone explain it to me what am I doing wrong, or what can solution be?

This is the code:

```
private void PlaySound()
    {
        output  = new SoundPlayer(location);
        output.Load();
        output.PlayLooping();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the file exists in your release folder when a relative path.

Comment: I used absolute path.

Comment: yeah, definitely check if the file exists, it might be in your debug folder, but not your release folder.

Comment: Audio file is in resources folder, i used full path to it, that is not a problem. If the file wasn't there the app would crash. For the sake of the argument I put it also in release folder and nothing changed. I read about situation similar to mine: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407473/mediaelement-is-playing-audio-only-in-debug-mode-its-not-playing-audio-without)